# Optimal Intensity training ratios

Tags: training, long-distance

I have used my googlefu now but I don't come up with any good research articles.

I read that a lot of elite riders train mostly on low intensity, is this the case and why?
To increase fet oxidtion, and endurance muscle fibers and decrease the risk of injury?

This article says that it is not good (in isolation) in higher levels:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_slow_distance

I also read something about 85/15 rule of race pace (85% of youre training should be lower then race speed and 15 % of the time at faster speed).

Answer (score 4):

Long slow distance is great for building up a strong aerobic base (circulatory and respiratory systems), if you have the time. However, unless you choose good rides it can be boring and few people would consider doing it on an indoor trainer.

For those who don't have that time, there's a century training plan in Chris Carmichael's [Time-Crunched Cyclist](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Crunched-Cyclist-2nd-Ed-Powerful/dp/193403083X) and most people would consider a century long-distance.

However, if you're not so concerned about getting a great time, then the amazingly-simple way to train for longer rides is to go out and ride, each time slightly increasing the distance. A bit more detail on [long-distance riding is given on YACF](https://yacf.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=85238.0).

Answer (score 2):

Yes to your entire second paragraph. A good reference would be Phil Maffetone's *The Big Book of Endurance Training and Racing.* His contention is that making the aerobic system more efficient is a healthier and more sustainable way to increase speed.

I'm an ultra distance cyclist who has tried both Maffetone and Carmichael's *Time-Crunched Cyclist*, and I've had much better luck with the former. Your experience may be much different if you're doing cyclocross or sprint races.

Answer (score 0):

Let's unpack the Wikipedia quote. All emphasis in quotes is mine.

> The moderate training intensity of LSD is effective in improving endurance and maximum oxygen uptake in individuals who are **undertrained or moderately trained**.

This corresponds to what I've written in answers where the questioners are looking for info on VO2max measurement and training. That is, in a general population, doing LSD will improve your aerobic fitness. This has been shown to be associated with lower mortality. Of course, those who prefer high-intensity intervals can certainly do that - more suffering but less time.

> [10] Although LSD training is not effective when used **in isolation** by well-trained athletes,[10] there is substantial evidence that elite athletes spend 70% or more of their training time at LSD output levels, that LSD effort levels are a necessary part of the training of world class athletes,[11] and that LSD workouts are primary drivers of the lower resting heart rates seen in well conditioned athletes.[12]

At my current level of training, my functional threshold power was more or less unchanged from early 2023 to March 2024. However, other aspects of my fitness, like time to exhaustion at threshold, increased very considerably. If I had *just* done LSD rides, I would not benefit at all (although I'd still have burned calories). In fact, most of my training had been oriented to rides near or at threshold, and my threshold power did not benefit at all. Anyway, this is what the Wikipedia is saying: in *trained* endurance athletes, doing *LSD alone* will not increase athletic performance.

To improve performance in *trained* endurance athletes, you need intensity. This is summed up in this diagram by Stephen Seiler:

[image]

Now people use the terms zone 2 rides or endurance rides, the former referring to about 55% to about 70% of threshold, this being in a 6-zone power model. The general thinking is that this builds your aerobic base. That is a vague term that encompasses some of the adaptations that the OP discussed. There are other adaptations that if you are actually interested in biology or sports science, you should research yourself.

You need at least some work at high intensity to progress. This includes rides near threshold, at threshold, and above threshold. And this work is tiring, so you will not be able to do a lot of it. This is why there's about an 80/20 ratio. In the past, cyclists used to race into shape, and the early spring races were considered training races. That is, they did zone 2 all winter, which built their endurance base, which in turn set them up to progress when they added intensity before the main part of the season.

> I also read something about 85/15 rule of race pace (85% of youre training should be lower then race speed and 15 % of the time at faster speed).

In modern discourse, there's been some talk about polarized intensity distribution. That is roughly equivalent to what the quote from the OP says. That is, about 20% of your riding should be hard. I think "hard" means near, at, and above threshold, in an appropriate mix for the athlete (e.g. an ultra racer may not need as much VO2max intervals). I am not sure if all athletes need to do all that 20% at *above* threshold intensity, as I think the OP implies in the quote. I think that competitive 10k runners may be racing at or just above threshold, whereas marathons may be more like what cyclists call the upper end of the tempo range (if referring to the 6-zone power model, [tempo is very roughly 75-90% FTP](https://www.trainerroad.com/blog/cycling-power-zones-training-zones-explained/)).

My understanding is that that 80/20 or 85/15 ratio may have been derived by sports scientists observing what elite endurance athletes did.

What if you are *very* time-constrained, like you have 2-4 hours a week? Should you do a much higher proportion of threshold or above-threshold work? Intuitively, it does seem like you would be a lot better off than nothing if you did so. I think that TrainerRoad, a popular cycling training website, may do this for their low volume plans. Nevertheless, you'll still benefit from fitting as much zone 2 in there as you can.